# Interpreting `(apply partial partial args)` in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, partial

I have faux-curry in [Programming Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure) book.

```
user=> (defn faux-curry [& args] (apply partial partial args))
#'user/faux-curry
user=> (def add-3 ((faux-curry +) 3))
#'user/add-3
user=> (add-3 10)
13
```

However, it's hard to see why two partials are needed in the body.

In [Coluredocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply), I see `(apply f args)` as an example of an apply function. How to interpret `(apply partial partial args)`?

Comment: Count yourself lucky there were only two `partial`s in the definition! An equivalent definition would be `(def faux-curry (partial partial partial))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to understand this is to expand out each part.

`(partial + 2)` returns a function
`(fn [& xs] (apply + 2 xs))`
calling the resulting function calls `+` with 1 and all the subsequent args passed to partial.

`(apply + 2 [3 4 5])` is the same as `(+ 2 3 4 5)`

`(fn [& xs] ...)` says "take a sequence of arguments and call them xs"
which is like `(fn [x1 x2 x3...] ...)`

`(partial partial)` returns a function
`(fn [& xs] (apply partial xs))`
which has exactly the same behavior as `partial` because the function it produces just directly calls `partial` with all the arguments.

`(apply partial partial args)`
is the same as
`(partial partial arg1 arg2...)`
returns
`(fn [& xs] (apply partial arg1 arg2... xs))`

`(apply partial partial [+ 1])` produces
`(fn [& xs] (apply partial + 1 xs))`.
Let's call this result `g`.
`(g 2)` => `(apply partial + 1 [2])` => `(fn [& xs] (apply + 1 2 xs))`. Let's call this result `h`. `(h 4 5)` => `(apply + 1 2 [4 5])` => `(+ 1 2 4 5)`

But if you were to leave out one of the partials:
`(apply partial [+ 1])` produces
`(fn [& xs] (apply + 1 xs)))`
calling this resultant function will not return a function, but the result of summing the arguments with 1.

So having observed these behaviors, let's attempt to describe
`(apply partial partial args)`:

"Create a function that creates a function that applies some function with the supplied arguments at creation time, and the supplied arguments at call time."

Hence `faux-curry` is a function that creates a function that creates a function o_O